# Is it possible to freeze headers in Sharepoint Lists without jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, header

There are a lot of questions on here for this answered with "use this jQuery plugin ", but I can't use jQuery (due to my work security controls).

Is it possible to freeze headers in Sharepoint Lists without using jQuery?

Comment: this light weight code works pretty well except in edge if you add the edit button to the list. Works pretty good in IE though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following JavaScript and CSS code for your reference.

```
<style type="text/css">
#LZheading {
    HEIGHT: 28px;
    display:none;
}
.FixedHeader{
    margin-top: -200px; 
    position: fixed;
    background-color:lightGray;
    display:block !important
}
#LZheading>table>tbody{
    visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    LZListScroll();
    document.getElementById("s4-workspace").onscroll=function(){
        var LZHead=document.getElementById("LZheading");
        if(this.scrollTop > 200){
            LZHead.classList.add("FixedHeader");             
        }else{
            LZHead.classList.remove("FixedHeader");         
        }
    }
};
function LZListScroll() {
    var LZmyTable=document.getElementsByClassName("ms-listviewtable")[0];
    var insertDiv=  document.getElementsByClassName("ms-csrlistview-controldiv")[0];    
    var LZHeadingDiv = document.createElement('div');
    LZHeadingDiv.appendChild(LZmyTable.cloneNode(true));
    LZHeadingDiv.id = "LZheading";
    insertDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(LZHeadingDiv,insertDiv.nextSibling);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm new to Sharepoint. How do I implement CSS code?

Comment: Add the code above(include CSS and JS) into a script editor web part in list view.

Comment: Ok - this capability may have been disabled by my organisation...

Comment: Unfortunately, the script doesn't work once we toggle to Quick Edit.
with error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLDivElement.document.getElementById.onscroll` and overrides vertical scrollbar and horizontal scrollbar below block. Couldn't find any workaround.

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

Freezing column headers in SharePoint list view is not possible using out of the box functionalities in SharePoint.

This concern is raised on SharePoint uservoice also. But it is not resolved yet, [Freeze column header](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/16077640-freeze-column-headers).

However this can be done using the custom javascript coding, maybe using jquery framework(Which you already know).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no OOB mechanism to freeze headers, so scripts are the solution to this issue.